# Creating a file association with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, installation, file-association

I am creating a program in vb.net, and I want to set my application as the default application for a given file extension - for example, `.txt`.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: What installer are you using?

Comment: I am creating my own installer with vb.net code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a simple way to associate files by vb.net (from CodeProject, link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18594/File-Association-in-VB-NET)

The code is:

```
My.Computer.Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(".rtf").SetValue("", "Rich Text File", Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.String)
    My.Computer.Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey("Rich Text File\shell\open\command").SetValue("", Application.ExecutablePath & " ""%l"" ", Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.String)
```

Comment: That basically does the same thing as I posted but in one line (and so it may make it difficult to find the error when something goes wrong). You will probably have to reboot the machine though for the changes to take effect if you don't use `SHChangeNotify`

Answer (score 6):

This sort of thing is usually handler by a dedicated installer program but you can do it using .net code although you program will need admin rights when running...

Have a look at this full example in VB.NET:

http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Tip/19554?type=kbArticle&trk=MSCP

Credit to Marco Bellinaso for the code. Here is the verbatim code to prevent link rot:

```
<System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("shell32.dll")> Shared Sub _
    SHChangeNotify(ByVal wEventId As Integer, ByVal uFlags As Integer, _
    ByVal dwItem1 As Integer, ByVal dwItem2 As Integer)
End Sub


' Create the new file association
'
' Extension is the extension to be registered (eg ".cad"
' ClassName is the name of the associated class (eg "CADDoc")
' Description is the textual description (eg "CAD Document"
' ExeProgram is the app that manages that extension (eg "c:\Cad\MyCad.exe")

Function CreateFileAssociation(ByVal extension As String, _
    ByVal className As String, ByVal description As String, _
    ByVal exeProgram As String) As Boolean
    Const SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED = &H8000000
    Const SHCNF_IDLIST = 0

    ' ensure that there is a leading dot
    If extension.Substring(0, 1) <> "." Then
        extension = "." & extension
    End If

    Dim key1, key2, key3 As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey
    Try
        ' create a value for this key that contains the classname
        key1 = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(extension)
        key1.SetValue("", className)
        ' create a new key for the Class name
        key2 = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(className)
        key2.SetValue("", description)
        ' associate the program to open the files with this extension
        key3 = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(className & _
            "\Shell\Open\Command")
        key3.SetValue("", exeProgram & " ""%1""")
    Catch e As Exception
        Return False
    Finally
        If Not key1 Is Nothing Then key1.Close()
        If Not key2 Is Nothing Then key2.Close()
        If Not key3 Is Nothing Then key3.Close()
    End Try

    ' notify Windows that file associations have changed
    SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED, SHCNF_IDLIST, 0, 0)
    Return True
End Function
```