# VB.net Startup program when clicking on desing file

Tags: vb.net, windows, icons, startup

I have made a program which will save a XML design file (with a custom extension *.xxx).

The icon I now see is an not recognized icon within windows (logic, because windows doesn't recognize *.xxx). So I want to have my own icon (same as "my program").

I also want to open "my program" when I click on the XML file.

Any suggestions or link examples?

Comment: You will need to create a file association. Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17186871/creating-a-file-association-with-vb-net

Comment: I included the File association Inno setup, but now when my vb.net application starts, I need the filename of my "design" file.

Comment: found it ;-)
        Dim strArg() As String
        Dim strArgFirst As String
        strArg = Command().Split(" ")
        strArgFirst = strArg(0)